# javascript deleting adding and deleting elements dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to let the user dynamically add languages with remove buttons for each one. I cannot figure out how to make the remove buttons work
Basically, I want the input text field removed if the X glyphicon next to it pressed
Thanks

```
        function setLanguage(){
              var l_name = document.getElementById("selected_language").value;
             var l_level = document.getElementById("lang_level").value;
       document.getElementById("sel_languages").innerHTML += "<div><input type = 'text'  readonly='readonly' name = 'language_selected1[]' value ='"  +  l_name  + " " + l_level  + "'/> <span id='language_clear' onclick='myFunction()'  class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle'></span></div>" ;

     }




  function   myFunction(){
            $(this).parent().remove();

    }
```

Comment: We'll need to see the html, and let us know what you tried.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `onclick` attribute of the html element, you can add `document.getElementById("language_clear").addEventListener("click", myFunction);` to the following line. I've posted a simple working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/0m73qsxp/5/).

w3schools has a nice article on event listeners [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp). If you'd prefer a jQuery version, you may want to check the documentation [here](https://api.jquery.com/click/); they have some nice examples.